# What is the point of the Ingalls test?

Tags: language-agnostic

The Ingalls test (named after Dan Ingalls, one of the designers of Smalltalk) for object-orientation says that you should be able to create a new kind of integer and use it in positioning a window on the screen.

I don't understand; what is the point of the Ingalls test?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for those of us who have never heard of the Ingalls Test?

Comment: @Matt Ball - I think I saw it in a book about Objective-C.

Comment: @Matt Ball: It's referenced [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671638): "Dan Ingalls, one of the designers of Smalltalk, proposed a test for whether a language is object-oriented. In an object-oriented language, a user should be able to create a new type of integer and use it to specify the coordinates for drawing in a system-provided window class."

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of it either, but this sounds like a test for how strictly object oriented and decoupled from explicit types a language is. This is a very big idea for Smalltalk, and dynamic languages in general.

So then, the Ingalls test seems like a litmus test for: *"Can we redefine some fundamental low-level concept in the language, and have that change work nicely all the way up through core libraries to something high-level like a GUI toolkit."*

So, a language like Java would fall down hard on this; "int" isn't even a proper object. However, strict object-oriented dynamically-typed languages should be able to manage this feat. You may want to read on the concept of [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), as it's closely related to the idea here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering completely off-the-cuff here but my guess would be that in a "properly" designed object-oriented language, integer would be an interface and you could develop your own implementation and use it anywhere the native integer was used.  I've never heard of this test but I like the idea of it.

I belive this test would exclude both C# and Java (although I haven't written any Java in a while so things may have changed).